# React dynamic form library accepting JSON schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, npm

I have a question if you know any library that allows you to generate the form / validate the form based on the JSON schema.

I am looking for anything before I start coding so I know if there is a way to get this sorted before.
I have seen `ajv` but I don't know any form generator library that works with it.

This is an example schema:

```
{
    "birthDate": {
        "type": "string",
        "format": "date",
        "pattern": "date{DD MMMM, YYYY}",
        "aem:affKeyword": [
            "DOB",
            "Date of Birth"
        ],
        "description": "Date of birth in DD MMMM, YYYY",
        "aem:afProperties": {
            "displayPictureClause": "date{DD MMMM, YYYY}",
            "displayPatternType": "date{DD MMMM, YYYY}",
            "validationPatternType": "date{DD MMMM, YYYY}",
            "validatePictureClause": "date{DD MMMM, YYYY}",
            "validatePictureClauseMessage": "Date must be in DD MMMM, YYYY format."
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you so much for the help!